# Short Marvel fanfic about Magneto having a head cold

Tags: story-identification, x-men, fan-fiction, magneto

I think I read this in college, which would put it online between 1998 and 2002. I thought I read it on the [Fonts of Wisdom](https://web.archive.org/web/20050212045417/http://home.att.net/%7Elubakmetyk/) site, but I can't find it on there. It was a short humorous fanfic where Magneto wakes up with a head cold, and realizes that he has no medicine in the house. I think he is also aware that his powers are going slightly haywire, with sneezes causing metal objects to fly around him. For some reason, I want to say he was in Switzerland, at least partially in hiding. He sets off to the pharmacy, not realizing that he has a procession of metal objects parading in his wake, gets to the pharmacy, and gets the medicine albeit with the clerk convinced he's being held up by the mutant terrorist. Then, the X-Men show up and there's a line along the lines of "Magneto raised his handkerchief and blew his nose with great dignity, causing the Blackbird to crumple into a small ball of metal."

Comment: hmm i saw your question on solveforum too

Comment: @shanu I'm pretty sure they're data mining us.

Comment: I fortunately didn't make an account there, just saw your question on a google search for the same question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the story you are looking for is *Magneto's Cold* by Lori MacDonald. Written in 1999, links to it have long since succumbed to link-rot, but a [copy](https://web.archive.org/web/19991103005034/http://alara.dreamhost.com/opeople/xbooks/cold.html) is still available thanks to the Wayback Machine.

Switzerland is not explicitly named, but Magneto is living by himself in a house "high on a mountain twenty miles from the nearest town, which was the only place for him to go within fifty to buy food." The penultimate line is almost as you recall:

> Regally, the mutant pulled out a Kleenex and blew his nose, debating
> internally the pros and cons of actually trying the cold remedies he'd
> gotten as he picked his way through the remains of the Blackbird.

Comment: Also available at http://alara.net/opeople/xbooks/cold.html